# Can I principally style the parent element based on child element using CSS3?

Tags: css

An Example: Only DIVs, that containing a LABEL should get the style `text-align: right`

Following try did not work:

```
div label:only-child {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Not the label but the div should get this style.

Comment: you want divs that only contain a label , i mean...the label is the only child of that div ? or are there other elements inside the div besides the label ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cant't do this in CSS only. Well, of course you can add class to div but there is no parent selector.
But there will be in the future (selectors lvl4 - see last row of selectors overview): https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/

Comment: That was the answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't style parent element based on child element using CSS.

Since, it seems that you are trying to align the label element to right, you can do that using `float` as shown below:

```
div label:only-child {
    float: right;    /* instead of text-align: right */
}
```

#### Updated (*parent has flexbox layout*):

```
div label:only-child {
  flex: auto;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: it is within a flex-box, float does not work there :/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way
div class="test" style="text-align:left" 
div class="test" style="text-align:right"

Comment: Inline stylings should be avoided because it directs to unmanageable code. So, define a class to that element and apply styles to that class in css file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the width of the label and display property to block. Here's the code

```css
div{
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
div>label:only-child{
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>adfasdf</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I've changed the title of my question dear @Kijan, because not the design is here the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this **cannot** be done with CSS .

CSS =  Cascading Style Sheets so by definition you can select elements from top to bottom of the HTML structure, not the other way around.

so you can't select a `parent` depending on it's `children`

you can do this with JQ , there are a number of ways to do it but this would be one of them :

```js
$( "div:has(label)" ).css({ "text-align":"right" });
```

```css
.div {
  height:50px;
  border:2px solid red;
   margin:2px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
<label>Has Label</label>
</div>
<div class="div">
<p>
i am NOT a label
</p>
</div>
<div class="div">
<label>Has Label</label>
</div>
```